# psfragfig no longer working if eps files are in subdirectory

Tags: mac, psfrag

I've been using `\psfragig` replacements for years on MacOS quite successfully.  My general workflow is to have my main `.tex` file in a directory and all of my image files (`bar*.eps`) along with the corresponding text replacement files (`bar*.tex`) in a subdirectory (`foo`) under the main directory.  I have never had any problems with this setup.

However, I just switched to a new machine (also a Mac) with an upgraded OS (Big Sur) and the process just described no longer seems to work.  If my images are in a subdirectory I get the following error:

> I can't write on file `foo/bar-pstool.tex'

The process works fine as long as the images are in the main directory so at least I know that I set the `--shell-escape` up correctly.  Perhaps it is some kind of OS permissions issue?

Any suggestions (other than don't use `\psfragfig` would be appreciated.

Comment: that's a low level file write error from the tex engine not under the control of the latex macros, so it normally relates to file permissions either at the operating system level or web2c  texmf.cnf settings (but the latter can only restrict writing in `../` parent directories not sub directories)

Comment: Thanks David.  Any ideas about what I could check or how to go about opening up the permissions?  Thanks.

Comment: no idea about macs, sorry:-)

Comment: No problem.  I actually tried changing openout_any = a in a local texmf.cnf to see if that would fix it but it did not.  Definitely some kind of OS level permissions problem.